# Is there a splat operator in VB .NET?

Tags: vb.net

I'm primarily a Python developer but I am unfortunately having to write a GUI-based program in VB .NET for a client. I've been able to figure out most of VB's peculiarities myself, but I've had no luck finding a way to translate this simple idiom into VB:

```
def my_function(arg1, arg2, arg3):
    # do stuff with args
    pass

args = [1,2,3]
my_function(*args)
```

I'm dealing with some nasty functions with lots of variables, and the code would be a lot nicer and more readable if I could do something like that so I'm not stuck with

```
MyFunction(reader(0), reader(1), reader(2), reader(3)) 'ad infinum
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sort of! First off, if it makes it more convenient for you, though, you can do the opposite. They're called parameter arrays:

```
Sub MyFunction(ParamArray things() As Whatever)
    ' Do something with things
End Sub
```

So these are equivalent:

```
MyFunction(reader(0), reader(1), reader(2), reader(3), ...)
MyFunction(reader)
```

But if you really want a splat-ish thing, then that's delegates:

```
Dim deleg As New Action(Of YourTypeA, YourTypeB)(AddressOf MyFunction)

deleg.DynamicInvoke(reader)
```

If you can't find an `Action` or `Func` to suit your needs, then you need to define your own delegate type to match:

```
Private Delegate Sub WayTooManyArgumentsDelegate(match arguments here)
```

and

```
Dim deleg As New WayTooManyArgumentsDelegate(AddressOf MyFunction)
```

Comment: thanks! I'll probably use the "easy" answer -- ParamArray -- but that's a super helpful hint about delegates. I'd never really understood what they were for and how to use them